# setting text on DataGridTextColumn

Tags: wpf, datagrid, datatrigger

I am using a DataTrigger to  replace empty cells with '-' text. My code:

```
  <DataGridTextColumn Header="Time taken" Binding="{Binding Path=finish}" Width="Auto" x:Name="x">
     <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
          <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
              <Style.Triggers>
                  <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=finish}" Value="{x:Null}">
                       <Setter Property="TextBlock.Text" Value="-" />
                   </DataTrigger>
               </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
     </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
  </DataGridTextColumn>
```

But I couldn't find the text being set. I tried  changing the background of the TextBlock and its working. Why cant I set the Text property?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Binding in the column might be overriding the `Setter`.

But you don't need a data trigger to do this. As there is a property in the binding that you can set for these kinds of scenarios.

TargetNullValue allows you to set a value in the case that the bindings path is null.

`Binding="{Binding Path=finish, TargetNullValue=Whatever you want}"`

Taken From:
[What's the simplest way to display NULL values as "NULL" with WPF Data Binding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/416088/whats-the-simplest-way-to-display-null-values-as-null-with-wpf-data-binding)

Comment: Hi val, Thanks for the easiest way!. BTW may I know why it wouldnt work in my way?

Comment: Val- The trigger seems to work, otherwise I wouldnt get the background property set. And yeh, I even tried setting the property to 'Text'. Didnt work :(

Comment: Yes, but you haven't explicitly bound the Background property in the columns declaration. So there's nothing to interfere with that working.

Comment: oh! so is there a way I can fix it? Or go with your solution?

Comment: In this instance it would be difficult to fix i think. Seeing as you're overriding a component of the column that will have bindings behind the scenes. If my solution works, then use it. Its a valid method.

Answer (score 3):

Namespace
xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Time taken" Binding="{Binding Path=finish}" Width="Auto"     x:Name="x">
 <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
      <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
          <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding Path=finish}"></Setter>
          <Style.Triggers>
              <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=finish}" Value="{x:Static sys:String.Empty}">
                   <Setter Property="Text" Value="-"></Setter>
               </DataTrigger>
           </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
 </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

Comment: May I know why you added this answer?

Comment: Since element style is overridden you need to set the text value  <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding Path=finish}"></Setter> and then set the trigger for checking for null or empty data for the datagrid cell.